# BASH unset -v problem - referenced vars are unset too

Tags: bash, reference, unset

Blindly relying on some statement claiming *'use unset-v or strange things will happen'*, I've been using `unset -v` since.
Now I've encountered following problem in conjunction with name references, where a referenced var is unset, too:

```
gitStatus=$(git status --porcelain=v1)
declare -n gitStatusResult=gitStatus
unset -v gitStatusResult 
echo -e "GIT_STATUS: ${gitStatus[@]}"
```

*gitStatus* will be empty, too after that, not just *gitStatusResult*. 
When using `unset -n gitStatusResult` or simply `gitStatusResult=` instead, the content of *gitStatus* will be preserved.

`unset --help` states, that:

> -v treat each NAME as a shell variable 
> -n treat each NAME as a name reference and unset the variable itself
> rather than the variable it references

This was unexpected - in my understanding things should be just the other way round, where `-n` should unset *gitStatus* directly, and `-v` should only unset the named reference *gitStatusResult*.

EDIT:
In addition, when using `unset -n gitStatus`, neither *gitStatus* nor *gitStatusResult* appear empty.

Could somebody shed some light on this issue?

I'm using `Cygwin GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release`.

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour in Linux, bash 4.4.23. But it seems to work correctly in 5.1.16.

Comment: I don't find this surprising. `-n` is how you bypass the normal behavior of a nameref, which is to be an alternate name for the same variable, not just another variable that happens to track the value of another. Regarding your edit, `gitStatus` is not a nameref, so `unset -n` shouldn't do anything to it.

Comment: BTW , the point of `unset -v foo` is to avoid undefining a function named `foo` if there is no variable `foo` to unset.

Comment: An aside - `${gitStatus[@]}` is superfluous and misleading; `gitStatus` is not an array here. The result will *coincidentally* be the same as `${gitStatus[0]}` or just  `$gitStatus`, but unless I am missing something, `${#gitStatus[@]}` will always be 1 (or zero, if there's *no* output, such as if `git`'s not in the `$PATH`). No matter how many lines `git status` returns, it's all treated as one string. If you wanted an array, try `mapfile -t gitStatus < <( git status --porcelain=v1 )` instead.

Comment: @ Paul Hodges: correct, this was causing `unset -n` having no effect on `gitStatus` above, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, I believe, the intended behavior of a nameref. A nameref is just that: a reference to a *name*, not a "real" variable itself. Anything you do to or with a nameref is equivalent to doing the same to or with the underlying variable.

```
foo=1
declare -n fooRef=foo

echo $fooRef  # same as echo $foo
fooRef=2      # same as foo=2
[[ -v fooRef ]]  # same as [[ -v foo ]]
unset -v fooRef  # same as unset -v foo
```

Note that the reference in the last case outlives the original variable; you can *still* use `fooRef` to revivify `foo`:

```
fooRef=5  # still the same as foo=5
```

As such, if you want to *remove* the nameref, you need some way to address it directly; that's what `unset -n` is for, bypassing the ordinary behavior of a nameref.

```
bash-5.2$ foo=1
bash-5.2$ declare -n fooRef=foo
bash-5.2$ declare -p foo fooRef
declare -- foo="1"
declare -n fooRef="foo"
bash-5.2$ unset -n fooRef
bash-5.2$ declare -p foo fooRef
declare -- foo="1"
bash: declare: fooRef: not found
```

Comment: I see - so for `unset -n` the doc actually means 'unset the *reference* itself rather than the variable it references' - then this makes sense, in conjunction with `gitStatus` in my example above not being an array, therefore, no effect for it by `unset -n`.